# Server side Blazor Role Group site authorization

Tags: c#, blazor

Im deploying a Server Side Blazor application and need to have the entire site limited to two windows role groups. In the past in MVC Ive done this through the web.config and it would be a simple matter. Im not seeing anything like this for Blazor. How can I setup windows role authorization for a Blazor site?

Ive googled this and have not found a site wide solution.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0 without more details it's going to be hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Ive looked at that and couldnt see how to apply it to this problem.  I have a Blazor server side application using windows authentication. I want to limit the site to role groups stored in the application jason config file. The groups would be stored as a comma delimited set of groups.  Im trying to make this work like the MVC sites worked were you just put the groups in the web.config. 
The closest thing Ive found so far is @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Superuser")]  but this would need to be on every page and the groups hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of able to implement what I was looking for. I created an AuthorizationRequirement that pulled in the groups from the appsettings file. Then created the handler that confirmed if the user was in one of those groups.

This works at the page level but I haven't figured out how to implement it at the site level. But at this point I may just settle for this working at the page level.